# DIV positioning is not working

Tags: html, css, layout

[image]

I'm surprised why this div float is giving too much a space on both ends. I have a parent DIV and 3 other child DIVs. The CSS code is below:

//This is the CSS for the parent DIV.

```
.row {
  width: 800px;
  background:#E3E3E3;
  height:50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px black;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

//This is the CSS for the middle DIV.

```
.element-field {
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

//This is the CSS for the left DIV.

```
.title-field{
    text-align:left;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    border:3px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

//This is the CSS for the right DIV.

```
.comment-field{
    text-align:left;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

//This is the HTML document

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="title-field"><label>This DIV is giving too much a space at left end and I don't understand why</label></div>
          <div class="element-field"><input name="lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="15" type="text" class="css-input" placeholder="ENTER LASTNAME" value=""></div>
          <div class="comment-field">This DIV is giving too much a space at the right end and I don't understand why</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I make the text fit into these DIVs without giving these gaps and not to allow text flow out of the DIV which is grey background? Your professional input is highly welcome.

EDIT:
Here is a fiddle with the code provided: http://jsfiddle.net/ohdjzxb4/

Comment: So is it needed to give `height:50px` to `.row`, because that is what making your text flow outside. Also you are using `position:absolute` for textfield change it to `relative`.

Comment: Please set up a working example on for example JSFiddle.net

Comment: Yes,Please give live demo so we can understand more your query

Comment: One of those divs has absolute position...so floating it will do ***nothing***

Comment: I think I have done some editing based on the professional suggestions, but just some few more steps to go. After editing, it's now appearing well but the DIV on the right doesn't align with the rest, pleas help me look into this. Appreciate. This is the Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ken4ward/vcsey14z/

Answer (score 0):

You can use table layout.

```css
.row {
  width: 800px;
  background:#E3E3E3;
  height:50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px black;
  padding-top: 5px;
  display: table;
}
.element-field {
  width: 80%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
text-align: center;
}
.title-field{
text-align:left;
width: 20px;
word-wrap:break-word;
border:3px solid #8AC007;
padding: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.comment-field{
text-align:left;
width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
word-wrap:break-word;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="title-field"><label>This DIV is giving too much a space at left end and I don't understand why</label></div>
      <div class="element-field"><input name="lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="15" type="text" class="css-input" placeholder="ENTER LASTNAME" value=""></div>
      <div class="comment-field">This DIV is giving too much a space at the right end and I don't understand why</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Done in:http://jsfiddle.net/wfo93rwn/

I hope this is what you expected.

CSS:

```
.row {
   width: 800px;
   background:#E3E3E3;
   height:150px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 2px black;
   padding-top: 5px;
   overflow:auto;
}

.element-field {
   width: 350px;
   vertical-align:middle;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 25px;
   float: left;
}

.title-field{
   text-align:left;
   width: 100px;
   float:left;
   word-wrap:break-word;
   border:3px solid #8AC007;
   padding: 10px;
}

.comment-field{
   text-align:left;
   width: 100px;
   word-wrap:break-word;
   float: right;
}
```